# Magento product import not displaying images in other stores

Tags: import, importexport

I've been struggling with this for the last couple of days and other links/suggestion I've seen have not helped. I've got 2 websites set up with one running off the main domain and the other works off a sub directory. Every thing works fine except when I try to import products, the images aren't showing on the other store and are replaced with a placeholder.

Has any one else come across this issue?

When add new products via the admin they work perfectly fine across both websites/stores so my configuration is correct, its just the import thats not working.

My import is here [import.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6PhgPlBw49KSHBDRFIzRDFkbDA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: now import image working fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its wasn't an import issue in the end. It was because some of the images where 300dpi and in CMYK format. Changed images and it worked perfectly